# Différence entre le futur proche et le futur simple

Tags: temps-grammatical, futur-simple, futur-proche, futur

Existe-t-il une différence entre le futur proche et le futur simple ?

Peut-on dire que la phrase *« il va faire chaud »* est égale à *« il fera chaud »* ?

Ou que *« je vais partir »* est égale à *« je partirai »* ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Une rapide recherche sur Wikipedia nous donne:

[Futur proche](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Futur_proche) :

> *[Le futur proche]* permet d'exprimer un événement dont on perçoit les signes avant-coureurs au moment présent (ex : Il va pleuvoir.), et qui va donc souvent se réaliser dans un court délai (d'où l'adjectif proche).

[Futur simple](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Futur_simple) :

> Son usage général [est une] action considérée comme à venir.

Donc non, ces temps expriment bien tous les deux une action future, mais dans des contextes différents.

Answer (score 2):

Le *futur proche* est pour les cas où quelque chose doit se produire dans l'avenir imminent. Le *futur simple* est un temps plus général, on l'utilise quand quelque chose se passera dans un pas si proche avenir.

Je crois que c'est similaire à « going to » et « will » en anglais, si vous ça aide. Ainsi, vous ne pouvez pas dire « il fera chaud » au lieu de « il va faire chaud » sans une certaine distorsion de sens.

Comment: Imminent?  Je ne crois pas.  Je vais faire une réponse plus complète expliquant pourquoi, mais pas avant deux ou trois ans.

Answer (score -3):

On peut aussi dire que le future en français est irrégulier et que dans la langue parlée le future avec aller est préféré. Je vais partir est égal à je partirai, mais en langue parlée la première forme est la forme normale.

Comment: Non, il ne sont pas employés dans les même contextes. Ce n'est pas une différence entre textes littéraires  et langage oral comme pour le passé simple.

Comment: Pourquoi écrivez-vous « future », et non pas « futur » ?

Comment: Au moment c'est très rare que j'écris en français. Il peut se faire qu'une forme anglaise se glisse dans mon français.

Comment: @rogermue: pourquoi dites-vous, que « Je vais partir est égal à je partirai » ?

Comment: Parce que je le crois. Les explications d'un futur proche et pas si proche sont d'une complexité qu'il faut dire que ce sont des interprétations. Au fond, un nouveau système du futur s'est dévelopé dans la langue parlée, parce que le futur normal est trop irrégulier, et maintenant les grammairiens veulent ètalir des règles. Souvent les grammairiens ont des difficultés s'il y a deux systèmes, l'un qui est vieux et l'autre qui est nouveau.

Comment: S'il y a deux systèmes il ne sert à rien d'inventer des règles quand il faudrait utiliser l'un et quand l'autre, simplement parce que les deux systèmes se chevauchent.

Comment: Trop irrégulier? Le futur simple est un des temps les plus réguliers du français! Les terminaisons sont identiques pour les 3 groupes, et sa formation (infinitif + terminaison, avec le possible -e final à enlever) n'accepte que "très peu" d'exceptions (être, avoir, faire, voir et leurs dérivés)

Comment: ... mais aussi venir, tenir, vouloir, pouvoir, savoir, devoir, mourir, courir, pleuvoir, envoyer... bref, pas de quoi remplir un Bescherelle! ;)